# How to browse available cars/quotes on Uber without providing credit card?

Tags: online-resources, tips-and-tricks, payment-cards, uber

I'd very interested in using Uber, and I'd like to have a look at what they have to offer in terms of available car sizes, rates, etc., but I can't work out how to do so without signing up which requires my credit card details. I have no intention of giving out those details without being to see what I might be paying for first, so surely there is a way of getting ride quotes without having to do so, as per accommodation and service-offering websites. Just can't seem to find it...

Comment: There really isn't.  But why the concern?  You don't get charged until you use it.

Comment: Because credit card information isn't something I ever give out unless I'm sure it's for a service that's valuable to me (in which case I consider it worth the risk).

Answer (score 6):

Simple: use a third-party site like [Uber Estimate](http://uberestimate.com/).  Obviously any results you'll get from here will be unofficial and not guaranteed, but they seem to be pulling data directly from the app.

Note that even in the Uber app itself, you don't have *precise* control over what you'll get: for most cities, your choices are basically "normal cars driven by random people" (UberX) and "luxury cars driven by pros" (UberBlack).  But it's not going to let you pick between a Ford Taurus and a Toyota Corolla.

Comment: Uber Estimate looks pretty accurate. Didn't know before - thanks. By the way, when you confirm and request the car, Uber does show the car type and driver name. You can cancel for free within the first few minutes if you don't like it. Not exactly choosing the car but you have the chance to cancel that Corolla.

Comment: It's ok, but I couldn't see how to get an estimate for UberXL. Specifically I want a car large enough to carry some oversize luggage items.  Even most SUV Taxis where I live now can't carry them because of the cage screens they have.

Answer (score 6):

Uber.com provides an official [Fare Estimator](https://www.uber.com/fare-estimate) now, which gives out a range for all types of transport.

[image]