# Price of a Uber fare from Charles de Gaulle airport to Amiens

Tags: paris, taxis, cdg

I am travelling from Charles De Gaulle airport to Amiens. How much would a Uber fare cost?

Comment: Uber fares depend greatly on time of day, traffic, the type of vehicle, etc. and are difficult to predict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61433/how-to-browse-available-cars-quotes-on-uber-without-providing-credit-card/61437#61437

Comment: Open the Uber app, plug in the start and end points, and it will give you the fare!

Answer (score 1):

Uber does have an online [estimate of fares](https://www.uber.com/en-AU/fare-estimate/):

Quickly plugging those in, as of April 2018, you'd get:

Your Options:

- UberBERLINE    225-300 €
- UberVAN    225-300 €
- uberX    147-197 €
- uberGREEN    147-197 €

Hope that helps with a rough idea. It might be cheaper to book a bus or rent a car, if possible for you.

Comment: I would look into rail travel, both locations are on the rail system and French trains are great, (if not on strike.)